# Codeigniter SQL query build

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-by, count

I'm having trouble to convert the below SQL query into CodeIgniter query builder:

```
$row = $db->prepare("SELECT DATE(message_timestamp) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT messageid) totalCount FROM ic_deliveryreceipts GROUP BY DATE(message_timestamp)");
```

This is the latest I've tried:

```
    $this->db->select(DATE(message_timestamp) as 'Date', COUNT(DISTINCT messageid) as 'totalCount');
    $this->db->group_by(DATE(message_timestamp));
    $query = $this->db->get($this->ic_receipts);
```

Any help more than welcome!
Thank you

Comment: For future reference, "$this->db->get($this->ic_receipts)" should be written as $this->db->get("ic_receipts"). You do not use $This in the name of the table.

Comment: @Brad, It appears the OP has set a class property (variable) to the name of the table, i.e. `$this->ic_receipts = "ic_deliveryreceipts";`  There is nothing wrong with that. Your comment is wrong because your example is not using the actual table name.

Comment: @DFriend I am sorry. I didnt see where he set the class variable

Answer (score 2):

```
$row = $this->db
              ->query("SELECT DATE(message_timestamp) Date, 
                       COUNT(DISTINCT messageid) totalCount 
                       FROM ic_deliveryreceipts 
                       GROUP BY DATE(message_timestamp)")
              ->row();
```

`$row` is a stdClass object with two properties: `Date`, `totalCount`

```
echo $row->Date . " " . $row->totalCount;
```

Comment: Thank you. Can't upvote your response unfortunately as my reputation is too low, sorry

Answer (score 2):

I think you need quotes, and also put false on the second (optional) parameter in `$this->db->select`, as seen in codeigniter docs:

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set
>   it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names. This is useful if you need a compound select statement where
>   automatic escaping of fields may break them.

Try writing like this:

```
$this->db->select("DATE(message_timestamp) as 'Date', 
                   COUNT(DISTINCT messageid) as 'totalCount'"
                  , FALSE);

$this->db->group_by("DATE(message_timestamp)");

$query = $this->db->get($this->ic_receipts);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally come up with:

```
$this->db->select('DATE(message_timestamp) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT messageid) totalCount');
$this->db->from('ic_deliveryreceipts');
$this->db->group_by('DATE(message_timestamp)');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Thank you for your suggestions